# Transposing a CSV in R so each row contains one data point

Tags: r, csv, text

I am trying to manipulate a CSV in R to match a very specific formatting need. Pretty confident I can nest a few loops to write to a file, but I'm hoping there's an easier way in R.

Before:

```
1,2,400,410,420,430,450,490,75700,75701,77035,77035,77035,77035
*,Facility Name,1234 Test Street,Michigan,49503,123-456-7891,,MPI_ID_TYPE,1,Sober Living Community,Clothing,Diapers,Food Pantry
```

After:

```
1,*
2,Facility Name
400,123 Test Street
410,TestCity
420,TestState
430,12345
450,123-456-7891
75700,MPI_ID_TYPE
75701,1
77035,Sober Living Community
77035,Clothing
77035,Diapers
77035,Food Pantry
```

So far, I have ingested data and manipulated it to achieve the Before chunk.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `t()` to transpose data.

```
 df <- mtcars[,1:2]
 df2 <- t(df)

df3 <- t(df2)
```

To further address your question I am keeping one row in the mtcars dataset. Then I use pivot_longer from tidyr to transpose and keep the original headers as a column in the data.

```
library(tidyr)
 df <- mtcars[1,]
 df2 <- pivot_longer(df, cols = everything())
```

Comment: Yep, I know of t(), but there's another step after transposing to force everything into two columns: column 1 is the original headers of the CSV, column 2 is the data. Ideas there?

Comment: do you want the column names to be a row

Comment: Thank you. I put together a for loop to append transposed data with rbind. I like pivot_longer(), but it looks like I'd still need a for loop to append multiple transposed rows to a single data frame.
<br/>
What I came up with that is working well:
~~~
    for(i in 1:nrow(pre_data)) {
      t1 <- t(rbind(head,pre_data[i,]))
      if(i == 1) {df <- t1
                  colnames(df) <- c("item","value")}
      else {df <- rbind(df,t1)}
    }
~~~